# How can I change my bash prompt to show my previous working directory?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, prompt, working-directory

In my ~/.bashrc I have

```
PS1='\w > '
```

which shows the current working directory.
But I want to see also the previous one.
something like this

```
~/Desktop () > 
~/Desktop () > cd ../
~ (/home/abgaryan/Desktop) >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$OLDPWD`:

```
PS1='\w ($OLDPWD) > '
```

Comment: isn't working (I have already checked). It always shows the same path

Comment: Can you please run `env -i bash --norc` to get a clean shell, then copy-paste (not retype or adapt) the line from this post into that shell? When you do `cd /tmp` followed by `cd /usr`, it should show `/usr (/tmp) >`

Comment: Can you please set that command in your .bashrc and try to run it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, it is ok now!

Answer (score 0):

$PWD instead of \w should do it for you.

you can test on the fly by running: export PS1="$PWD"

probably already knew that but making sure i'm new to posting :-)

Comment: $PWD will show the current one. Want to see the previous

Comment: sounds like you may do some PROMPT_COMMAND functions for that one.

edit: link: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html

Comment: PROMPT_COMMAND is for the terminal title. But I got the answer from the previues reply. Thanks!

Comment: GREAT! none of what i says matters but for future if someone happens on this.... 

PROMPT_COMMAND runs before showing the prompt..... (edit darn enter button)..

so if you set PROMPT_COMMAND = "date" your promt will look something like this:

Mon Apr 26 23:32:50 UTC 2021 [user]@[terminal]:~$

really powerful really.. just set your PROMPT COMMAND to what you want and PS1 to nothing..